# How to make carousel smooth scroll to top when next slide and use 'hand carousel'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I use carousel bootstrap 3 to use slide text. When the row#1 text is long to bottom (ex: height 300px) and the row#2 text is too short (ex:just 10px), The problem is we always must scroll to top as manually when we click next to row#2 from row#1. How to make when next slide, the system will 'smooth scrolling' to top as automatically???

In other hand, How to user can use 'hand carousel' ??? (I don't know the technology name but user just tap to right on mobile when want to next slide) when use mobile so its easy next slide without go to bottom again (find the carousel again) (this issue important when mobile ).

This is simple code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
  interval: false
})
});
```

But full code in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luisan/B9FeP/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could tap into the carousels slide event and then add the jquery scroll top function

```
$('#carousel-example-generic').bind('slid', function () {
   console.log('slid event');
   $('.carousel-inner').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Maybe using body would be better

```
   $('body').scrollTop(0);
```

You can also add in an animation that would look nicer

```
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
```

Comment: could you please update on jsfiddle? I have check your script but its not working.. thanks for your help